# Arrow function with return in reduce call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

```
//Example 1:
var primaryColors = [
  { color: 'red' },
  { color: 'blue' },
  { color: 'yellow' },
];

var answer = primaryColors.reduce((x,y) => x.push(y.color) , []);
//x.push is not a function



//Example 2:
var ints = [1,2,3];
var sum = ints.reduce((sum, number) => sum + number, 0);
//sum = 6
```

As shown above, Example 1 will be throwing exception `TypeError: x.push is not a function`. In order to make it works, we can add a pair of curly braces and returning value as below.

```
var answer = primaryColors.reduce((x,y) => { x.push(y.color); return x;}, []);
```

Now I don't really understand the need of `return`. Why Example 2 can sum without using the keyword `return` while Example 1 needed a return keyword in order to work?

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs on what `reduce` does? See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: The problem is that `x.push()` returns the new length of the array, so that's what your callback to `.reduce()` returns. But you need to `return x` from that callback for your code to have a chance at working properly.  The second time your callback is called, `x` will be `1` and `1.push()` is an error.  If you don't understand why you need `return x`, then study the doc for `.reduce()` more thoroughly.  `x` is the accumulator and the value of `x` in the next iteration of your callback will be whatever you return from the prior one.

Comment: @jfriend00 could you post an answer with this? otherwise question will stay unanswered because there is no other right answer except yours

Comment: Why with all the downvotes? Am I using the site wrongly? If the sole reason for the downvotes is because I didn't managed to understand the documentation then I guess there is no purpose for this site to even exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does Example 1 need a return keyword in order to work?

The problem is that `x.push()` returns the new length of the array, so that's what your callback to `.reduce()` returns. But `.reduce()` will take the return value from your callback and pass it as the next value for `x` in the next iteration of the loop.  So you need to `return x`.

The way you're doing it, the second time your callback is called, `x` will be `1` and `1.push()` is an error.

If you don't understand why you need `return x`, then study the doc for `.reduce()` more thoroughly.  `x` is the accumulator and the value of `x` in the next iteration of your callback will be whatever you return from the prior one.

> Why Example 2 can sum without using the keyword return

Because your example 2, returns `sum + number` which is what you want passed as sum for the next iteration of the loop.  So, it's returning the right thing.

---

FYI, your first loop is perhaps more easily done with `.map()`:

```
//Example 1:
var primaryColors = [
  { color: 'red' },
  { color: 'blue' },
  { color: 'yellow' },
];

var answer = primaryColors.map(item => item.color);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the way I was doing it, the second time my callback is called, `x` is not `1` because first iteration was `x.push(y.color)`

Comment: @Isaac -  The return value of `x.push()` is the length of the array `x` after the push.  That length will be `1` after the first push because the array was originally empty and then you pushed one element into it.  But, you can just `console.log(x)` if you want to see what it is.